# SQL Server fragmentation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need  **FRAGMENTATION** in SQL Server with *examples*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You should have typed that into Google. Better results, and faster, and no negative scores.

Comment: @jarlh As [it turns out](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103112), this is not a homework question …   ☹

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.create a table with some GUID as primary Key
2.do inserts and check fragmentation
3.Rebuild check Fragmentation

you also can do search like below for more SO Examples

> sql server fragmentation site *.stackexchange.com

simple Demo:

```
create table test1
(
id varchar(255) primary key default newid()
)

insert into test1
default values
go 100


--check fragmentation
select avg_fragmentation_in_percent, avg_fragment_size_in_pages, fragment_count, avg_page_space_used_in_percent
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), object_id('test1'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')

--rebuild index
ALTER INDEX ALL ON test1
REBUILD  

--check fragmentation
select avg_fragmentation_in_percent, avg_fragment_size_in_pages, fragment_count, avg_page_space_used_in_percent
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), object_id('test1'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```